# Making Raspberry Pi Bluetooth slave

Tags: bluetooth

I'm trying to setup my Raspberry Pi's bluetooth to listen and wait to be paired by a PC . I see most of the guides are the other way (Raspberry Pi scans, detects and pairs to other devices). How can this be done?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 7):

You need to activate the ISCAN service to achieve this:

```
sudo hciconfig hci0 piscan
```

after this, when you execute `sudo hciconfig -a`, you should see this line:

```
UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN
```

After that, just run `bluez-simple-agent` and when the Agent is started (don't kill the process), use the other device to scan and find the RPI.
Start the pairing and you will get the PIN prompt in the console. When done, the devices are paired. You can stop the bluez-simple-agent with CTRL+C.

If you want to add the device as trusted, execute:

```
bluez-test-device trusted XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX yes
```

where `XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX` is the bluetooth device address.

Comment: `bluez-test-adapter` was replaced by `bluetoothctl` now

Answer (score -1):

Check this may help you if you want to receive or send data..

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92255/how-do-i-connect-and-send-data-to-a-bluetooth-serial-port-on-linux

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.